# I want to use raspberry pi 3 in Access point and Wifi client mode,both modes can be switched with hardware toggle switch?

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I am working on a project in which i need to connect raspberry pi3 to wifi network.

I want to put my Raspberry Pi 3 in AP mode and connect to its wifi (through mobile) and go to a webpage hosted on it to enter the wifi ssid and password to which the Pi is later connected, when switched to wireless client mode.

Comment: And what will you do if the RasPi is connected as client to a remote hotspot without its own access point? As far as I understand the RasPi is headless.

Answer (score 0):

While it is certainly possible to create a hardware button to do this, it does seem a bit overkill.

Easier would be to just let the Pi connect to networks it knows, and if no such network is found, it can switch to AP mode. Once an SSID and a password is entered, the Pi can turn off AP mode, try to connect, and cycle back to AP mode again if the connection still fails.

Comment: Nice explained with some words, but does it work? How exactly would you setup this?